# Permanent link to JetBrains App installed via JetBrains Toolbox

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I use [JetBrains Toolbox](https://jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) to manage my JetBrains apps.

Whenever a new version of IntelliJ IDEA is installed it gets a new directory under `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U` folder.

These directories are named `ch-0`, `ch-1` aso. in order to have the current and previous version installed. This makes switching back to the previous version simple if something doesn't work with the new version.

On the other hand, I would like to open a file or project via command line. So, I need a link to the current IntelliJ IDEA executable. This link breaks after every update.

Is there a hidden feature of the JetBrains Toolbox or does anybody have an other idea to archive a permanent link to the current version?

Comment: *"So, I need a link to the current IntelliJ IDEA executable"* 1) Each IDE should have own command line launcher (e.g. `webstorm` for WebStorm, `phpstorm` or maybe `pstorm` for PhpStorm, `idea` for IntelliJ IDEA and so on). Check them in action + see if you can regenerate them from Toolbox app (should be) so they point to the latest version. 2) What if you select "Keep only the latest version" option (to keep only 1 version installed)?

Comment: I did not have such a launcher, bc the option could be disabled in JetBrains Toolbox. I wasn't aware of such an option..

Comment: This helped me, https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/enable-shell-scripts-for-the-jetbrains-toolbox-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jetbrains Toolbox offers an option to generate shell scripts. That option was disabled.

Simply enable `Generate shell scripts` and choose a location where a link to that script should be created.
After the option was enabled an a shell script location was selected, the script and link was created immediately.

The screenshot should make things really clear:

[image]